# How to chain a task to a previous instance of it?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, async-await

Looking to chain a task to a previous instance if it exists. Currently, both are executed at the same time.

Initial code that works for *one* task :

```
    private async void MenuMediaAddFiles_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = GetDefaultOpenFileDialog();
        using (dialog)
        {
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (var progress = new SimpleProgress(this))
                {
                    int addFiles = await _context.AddFiles(dialog.FileNames, progress);
                    Console.WriteLine("Files added: {0}", addFiles);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

A failed attempt to make it work :

```
    Task<int> _files;
    private async void MenuMediaAddFiles_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = GetDefaultOpenFileDialog();
        using (dialog)
        {
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (var progress = new SimpleProgress(this))
                {
                    int addFiles;
                    Task<int> files = _context.AddFiles(dialog.FileNames, progress);
                    if (_files == null)
                    {
                        _files = files;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var task1 = await _files.ContinueWith(task => _context.AddFiles(dialog.FileNames, new SimpleProgress(this)));
                    }

                    addFiles = await _files;
                    Console.WriteLine("Files added: {0}", addFiles);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need the `await` on the line with `ContinueWith()`? What happens without it?

Comment: If I remove it I still get the same result.

Comment: I'm confused about what behavior you want.  Do you want to await a previous task if it exists?  When the previous task exists what do you want to do about the task returned from _context.AddFiles?

Comment: Whenever the user clicks to add files, the task 'AddFiles' should run after a previous 'AddFiles' task should there be one running. Just like a media player, when you enqueue files they get played sequentially, not simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were pretty close, but there were a few things that needed to be modified:

```
private Task<int> previousTask = Task.FromResult(0);
private async void MenuMediaAddFiles_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dialog = GetDefaultOpenFileDialog();
    using (dialog)
    {
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (var progress = new SimpleProgress(this))
            {
                previousTask = previousTask.ContinueWith(t =>
                    _context.AddFiles(dialog.FileNames, progress))
                    .UnWrap(); ;

                int addFiles = await previousTask;
                Console.WriteLine("Files added: {0}", addFiles);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Things to note:

- Rather than having the previous task be `null` sometimes, it was easier to initialize it to an already completed task (`Task.FromResult(0)`).  This avoids the null check code.
- You were calling `AddFiles` twice.  You shouldn't have been calling it before the `if`, and you weren't ever assigning the task to the instance field inside the `if`.
- I used `UnWrap` instead of `await` to turn the `Task<Task<int>>` into a `Task<int>`.  Both work, but in this case I felt `UnWrap` made its intentions clearer.
- Note that since the entire event handler will be running in the UI thread there's no need to synchronize access to `previousTask`, if it doesn't, you'd need to do some locking.

Comment: “there's no need to synchronize access” So why do you have the `lock` there?

Comment: @svick Right, updated my code and forgot to copy it over again, fixed.